# How can I make a bot give multiple responses to one case?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I wanted to make a bot that gave multiple responses to one trigger case, but as I am only a novice with coding still, I do not know how to. I ask because I am recreating a key thing from a game, and one of the codes has multiple responses to it. I have pasted all the code with changes to shorten it.

I checked online to find out, but none matched my code at all or showed no example of placement.

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
token: auth.token,
autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
logger.info('Connected');
logger.info('Logged in as: ');
logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
    bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
    case '7378':
        bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'Response TEST'
                });
            break;
    case '5653':
        bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'Response JOKE 1'
                // JOKE has multiple responses to the case. It is the one I'm looking to add the extra responses to.
                });
            break;
    case '5683':
        bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'Response LOVE'
                });
            break;
    case '1841':
        bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'Response QUIZ'
                });
            break;
    case '8368':
        bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'Response VENT'
                });
            break;
    case '2673':
        bot.sendMessage({
        to: channelID,
        message: 'Response CORE'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to.
         }
     }
});
```

I should expect to have multiple responses to the JOKE code (5 possible responses).

Comment: For the response to Joke 1 are you looking to have an random response returned from the potential results or are you looking to have all of the potential responses returned ?

Comment: One response out of five of the possible JOKE responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the Math.random() function to help return a random answer to the joke

```
case '5653':
    switch (Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)){
    case 0:
        messageVal = "First Joke answer";
        break; 
    case 1:
        messageVal = "Second Joke answer";
        break; 
    case 2:
        messageVal = "Third Joke answer";
        break; 
    case 3:
        messageVal = "Forth Joke answer";
        break; 
    case 4:
        messageVal = "Fifth Joke answer";
        break; 
    }
    bot.sendMessage({
    to: channelID,
    message: messageVal
            });
        break;
```

This works from the assumption that there's no condition for what response gets sent back.

Answer (score 0):

Put your messages in an array

```
    bot.sendMessage({
      to: channelID,
      messages: [
        {
          id: 1,
          message: 'Response JOKE 1'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          message: 'Response JOKE 2'
        }
      ]
    });
```

Then you could randomly retrieve one based on its index in the array nested in your object, or assign each message an id and use those, or whatever else you want to do

Comment: Tested. SyntaxError: Unexpected token. 43 - '}' Without it, : instead.

Comment: Ah sorry I had a typo { was a }. It is correct now.

Comment: Success to an extent. Now it doesn't respond to the case anymore.

Comment: Sorry I was at work and couldn't follow up. If you're interested in using the above method you would have to change the method call up a bit. If you need further help let me know and I can get more in depth.